# Subclassing Dict, Class variables

Tags: python

I am trying to piece together some example code, and I ran into a bit that didn't quite make sense to me. Without including the entire source, I will try to target what I consider the important sections, and hopefully I get it all.

Here, he declares a custom dict subclass, with what I thought should be class variables 'customer' and 'film'. (as in, setting these from one class, should update them in all instances, yes?)

```
class Payment(dict):
    customer = film = None
```

And here is where he uses the Payment...

```
columns = [item[0] for item in cursor.description]
payments = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    payment = Payment(zip(columns, row)) #I believe this is where he loads dict items
    payment.customer = customers[payment["customer_id"]] #This is where he assigns 'class variable'
    payment.film = films[payment["film_id"]]
    payments.append(payment)
```

In the final list, shouldn't all 'payments' have the same values (which turns out to be another dict)? This is where my confusion is.

It turns out that those two attributes had unique values across the board. Does this have to do with subclassing Dict? Are the values copied rather than referenced (so technically they are class variables, but since they are copied, they continue to remain unique).

Just when I thought I understood the simple OO mechanics, this throws me...

Answer (score 4):

In the following:

```
payment.customer = customers[payment["customer_id"]] #This is where he assigns 'class variable'
payment.film = films[payment["film_id"]]
```

you're not changing the values of `payment.customer` and `payment.film`. Instead, you're *rebinding* them, making them specific to the *instance* of the class.

Consider the following example:

```
class X(object):
  val = ['orig']

x1 = X()
x2 = X()
x3 = X()
x1.val = ['rebound']      # rebind
x2.val[0] = 'modified'    # modify in place
print x1.val, id(x1.val)
print x2.val, id(x2.val)
print x3.val, id(x3.val)
```

This prints

```
['rebound'] 2907552
['modified'] 2771544
['modified'] 2771544
```

Observe how `x1.val` becomes a completely separate variable once it's been rebound, whereas `x2.val` and `x3.val` continue to both refer to the same list.

Answer (score 2):

When Python looks up an attribute on an object, it first looks at the instance, then at the class and then the super classes.

After this

```
payment = Payment(zip(columns, row)) #I believe this is where he loads dict items
```

You can check that `payment.__dict__` has no entries for `customer` or `film`

If you try to access (getattr) `payment.film`, since the instance has no `film` attribute, you'll get `payment.__class__.film`.

Assigning attributes always (unless it's a descriptor) will create the entry in the instance dict, and so it is isolated from all the other instances.

And some interpreter fun:

```
>>> class C(dict):
...  foo = "class foo"
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> c.__dict__
{}
>>> c.foo
'class foo'
>>> c.foo = "instance foo"
>>> c.__dict__
{'foo': 'instance foo'}
>>> c.foo
'instance foo'
>>> del c.foo
>>> c.foo
'class foo'
```

Incidentally, since the code in your example doesn't access those class attributes, this would work just as well:

```
class Payment(dict):
    pass
```

The author may prefer to "declare" those attributes for some reason, but it's not necessary (and possibly confusing) to have them there in this case.

Comment: I've seen this technique used in cases where creating the instance doesn't always initialise all of the instance attributes. In that case it can be a useful way to give a default value to an instance attribute that may or may not be initialised in the instance. `pyramid` uses this style quite a lot.

Comment: NPE's answer helped, but this one better illustrated attribute lookup. I think I was confused because normally my class variable access from the instance is usually read-only. I only ever write to class variable from staticmethod.

Comment: If I did want to treat 'foo' (as in your example) as a class variable explicitly from within my instance, would I need to use C.foo from my instance methods? (assume the variable is an integer)

Comment: @user2097818, Yes, but you should to consider what behaviour you want for subclasses of C. eg `self.__class__.foo` will let you set the attribute of a sublass for an instance of that subclass. This is usually what you really want

Comment: I probably should be making a staticmethod call that returns the same "static value" reference to all instances, in my head though it seems like for trivial integer lookup this is overkill.